# two are placed one on top of other ..remove above image in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a web application of a memory game where I am drawing both the images using canvas  one image is in top of other image I want to remove above image .Currently I am using clear rectangle which removes the both image. I am using the following function which removes both images.

```
     ctx.clearRect(card.sx,card.sy,card.swidth,card.sheight);
```

please note I don't want to redraw the second image again.

Comment: Can you use two `<canvas>` and "stack" them together, and make the top one `display:none` when necessary?

Comment: Simply put, no can do. The canvas doesn't store it's image as a series of images, but rather as pixels. Once a pixel is overwritten, it's old value is gone. The only instance I can think of is the XOR composition mode - totally unsuitable for you though - since you could make out detail of both cards. See here for a small demo of canvas composition-modes. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/html5-canvas/composition.html

Comment: @enhzflep,@Passerby  cant i use fading for this I mean cant I fade the image on top....and simply draw a new image... do you know how to fade a image in html 5 in javascript,,,,

Comment: Yes, you could indeed draw the 'ontop' image with decreaesd opacity - BUT, to animate a fade-in, fade-out, you need to re-draw _both_ cards repeatedly. Why not just redraw the card underneath again? If it's difficult to keep track of which image it is, your design needs reviewing.